# Insert cart data into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, shopping-cart

This is my code to insert my data in my shopping cart into the database.The problem is it works when there is only 1 data in the cart. How do i make it work if there more than 1 item in the cart.  The reason i send it to the database is so that the admin can view the order to prepare it.

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
?>
<?php
include("dbase.php");
include("functions.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])){
if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$address=$_REQUEST['address'];

$sum=get_order_total('grandTotal');

$result=mysql_query("insert into bloom_customers    values('','$name','$address','$phone','$sum','$date','$time','$banks')");
$customer_id=mysql_insert_id();
$date=date('Y-m-d');

$result=mysql_query("insert into bloom_orders values('','$date','$customer_id')");
$orderid=mysql_insert_id();


$max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
    $proid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['product_id'];
    $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
    $price=get_price($proid);
    mysql_query("insert into order_details values ($orderid,$proid,$q,$price,$customer_id)");
    $customer_id=mysql_insert_id();
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='ordersubmitted.php' </script>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't overwrite customer_id in the last line of the for block?

Comment: Also, you should consider a header() call to redirect after success rather than using js.

Comment: are you getting in your $max variable all the items?

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the `for` loop is:

```
$customer_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

That means that the customer value is changing for each insert.  I think you mean:

```
$orderdetail_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

Also, you don't need to store the customer id in the `order_details` table.  It is already in the `orders` table.

And, finally, all your inserts should have explicit column lists, such as:

```
$result=mysql_query("insert into bloom_orders(date, customer_id) values('$date', '$customer_id')");
```